# Fortrabbit: How to set composer install as default method?

Tags: php, deployment, composer-php, fortrabbit

On my Fortrabbit app, I use the Git hook (via commit message) to trigger Composer. This will run a `composer update`. Is there a way to trigger `composer install` per default instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new deployment file to do this:

1. Create a text file called `fortrabbit.yml`.
2. Place that file in your document root within Git version control.
3. Edit the content as seen in the example below.
4. Push the file.
5. Trigger Composer as usual with `[trigger:composer]` in your commit message.

---

```
version: 1
composer
    method: install
```